# Grub Loading error after partition during booting

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have error during boot after partition of laptop. It have Window XP and Ubuntu 9.04 Os.
GRUB Loading Stage1.5
Grub Loading Please wait
ERROR 17

```
Device Boot  Start  End    System
/dev/sda1    1      2582   HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2    6854   7296   Hidden W95 FAT32(LBA)
/dev/sda3    2853   6853   W95 Ext'd(LBA)
/dev/sda5    5518   5779   Linux Swap
/dev/sda6    2853   5517   W95 FAT32
/dev/sda7    5780   6853   Linux
```

Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it looks like there are 5 headings and 4 columns of data. The missing column would be under Boot. Use a Live CD and take a look here.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1489071

Although the table is simple, I'm not familiar with its origin. If no luck, from the terminal type df and post the results back.